# How to receive data through udp (in python) known the source IP address and port?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, udp

I know there is a UDP stream being sent from an ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port xxxx, how do I receive that data in python.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is using socket

import socket

```
import socket


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

Comment: I did the same for the following IP and port 

UDP_IP = '192.168.x.xx'
UDP_PORT = 5555

and I get the following error
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: Are you sure is UDP stream coming from that IP? maybe is a TCP and you have to change `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` for `socket.SOCK_STREAM`

Comment: I verified it using a tool wireshark, I could see that it's a UDP protocol.